# How to manipulate a rows in a file using bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file which has records from a table.

It has this format. Each column is separated by tabs

```
UUID                                      number          name
ac500f63-630d-4048-90cf-74bc85c1101c       1              Kane
47493ed9-008b-4dd6-88dc-d91fa64225b3       3              NULL
```

What I want to do is : columns need to be comma separated. and UUID and name columns need to be wrapped in single quotes and not enclose in single quotes when name is NULL. Even a row needs to be comma separated.

the sample output for the above is

```
'ac500f63-630d-4048-90cf-74bc85c1101c', 1, 'Kane'

'47493ed9-008b-4dd6-88dc-d91fa64225b3', 3   NULL
```

I will need these values for an INSERT query. Is there a way to achieve this with `sed` or `awk` commands ?

Comment: On SO we do encourage all users to add their own efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so kindly do so and let us know.

Comment: *I will need these values for an INSERT query.* So... Are you actually asking how to import this file into a database?

Comment: Looks like you'd want to import TSV-formatted data into your DB, which most DBMS handle natively. You should look into this (websearches for "<DBMS> import TSV" seem to give good results) as it will be easier and more robust.

Comment: Is the missing comma after `3` a typo?

Answer (score 0):

```
cat l.txt
UUID                                      number          name
ac500f63-630d-4048-90cf-74bc85c1101c       1              Kane
47493ed9-008b-4dd6-88dc-d91fa64225b3       3              NULL


cat p.sh
#!/bin/bash
awk '
NF == 3 && NR >= 2 { m=$3=="NULL"?32:39;printf("%c%s%c,%s,  %c%s%c\n",39,$1,39,$2,m,$3,m);}
' $1

./p.sh l.txt
'ac500f63-630d-4048-90cf-74bc85c1101c',1,'Kane'
'47493ed9-008b-4dd6-88dc-d91fa64225b3',3, NULL
```

I hope it will good for you.